# PHImageManager crashing after many image requests

Tags: ios, ios8, photokit, phasset

I'm trying to grab all of the users `PHAsset` with `PHAssetMediaTypeImage` and then iterate through them, getting the corresponding `UIImages` one at a time. I have about 2k photos on my iPhone 5 and this code crashes after iterating through 587 of them.

```
PHFetchResult *fr = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:nil];

PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.synchronous = YES;
__block int i = 0;
for (PHAsset *result in fr)
{

    [manager requestImageForAsset:result targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:options resultHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info) {
        NSLog(@"%d", i);
        i++;
    }];
}
```

The exception reads EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0). Any help pointing me in the right direction on this will be enormously appreciated.

Comment: If you take another photo, does it still fail at 587, or does it then crash at 588? Why are you trying to do this? If you give more context we might be able to offer an alternative approach, as this doesn't sound like an optimal approach to take.

Comment: @Stephen Did you figure it out? I am seeing the same issue and I would love to hear what you found out. If you don't have an answer, it would be useful to post the stack trace of the crashing thread I think

Comment: I wasn't able to figure it out. I've put that project on hold for a while but I think when I get back to it I'll take a different approach and process images in batches, unless Apple has fixed the bug by then.

Answer (score 1):

Closing the loop on this one. The images don't get released until the for loop completes so you need to put an @autoreleasepool to drain the pool after each iteration of the loop, like so

```
PHFetchResult *fr = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:nil];
PHImageManager *manager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.synchronous = YES;
__block int i = 0;
for (PHAsset *result in fr)
{
    @autoreleasepool {
    [manager requestImageForAsset:result targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:options resultHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSDictionary *info) {
            NSLog(@"%d", i);
            i++;
        }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was found in the this line of code

```
   PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .AspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: {(result, info) in cell.setThumbnailImage(result)
    })
```

The parameter, targetSize was passed the value of PHImageManagerMaximumSize which was the culprit. I changed it to `lCgSize`, `lCgSize = CGSizeMake(105, 105);` resolved the issue.

According to the documentation PHImageManagerMaximumSize

> When you use the PHImageManagerMaximumSize option, Photos provides the
>   largest image available for the asset without scaling or cropping.
>   (That is, it ignores the resizeMode option.)

So, this explains the problem. I believe if it was a single image, it should not be a problem but if it was many images, the device would run out of memory.